# web based jmx monitoring

Tags: jmx, jconsole

We have around 25 JVM which we are monitoring using JConsole

We are primarily interested only to view the Heap Memory and CPU usage of these 25 JVM process

Is there a simple web tool which can be pull these metrics from different jconsole and display in a dashboard?
Manually logging into each jconsole and monitoring at the time of production incidents is a time taking procedure

Pls help if any such tool is available

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for any licensed tool? There are many tools available in the market with various range. https://blog.overops.com/java-performance-monitoring-5-open-source-tools-you-should-know/

When you are interested only in CPU & Heap , you can try https://www.eginnovations.com/product/java-performance-monitoring